# CLLocationManager Not Working On Device

Tags: ios, swift, cllocationmanager

I have written a basic program that uses the devices location.  I have written it and this is the basics of the ViewController

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    self.locationManager.delegate = self
    self.locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
    self.locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
    self.locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
}

func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
    print("Location Updated")
    lat = String(format: "%f", locationManager.location!.coordinate.latitude)
    long = String(format: "%f", locationManager.location!.coordinate.longitude)
}

func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager, didFailWithError error: NSError) {
    print("Failed Loc: \(error)")
}

func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager, didChangeAuthorizationStatus status: CLAuthorizationStatus) {
    print("Auth Changed: \(status)")
}
```

In my info.plist I have this, as required:

```
<key>NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription</key>
<string>uses loc</string>
```

I ran the code on the simulator and it gives me

```
Failed Loc: Error Domain=kCLErrorDomain Code=0 "(null)"
```

I then sepcified the location of the simulator and it prints

```
Location Updated
```

as it should.  Oddly; however, when i upload this onto my ios device it asks for permission and then I get no output.  There are no errors that output, it doesn't even trigger didChangeAuthorizationStatus

**Edit: here is the header of the ViewController file:

```
import CoreLocation

class Central_ViewController: UIViewController, UIScrollViewDelegate, UITabBarDelegate, CLLocationManagerDelegate {

    let locationManager = CLLocationManager()
```

**Edit 2:

```
self.locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
    if(CLLocationManager.locationServicesEnabled()) {
        print("Location Services Enabled")
        self.locationManager.delegate = self
        self.locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
        self.locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
    }else {
        print("Location Services NOT Enabled") // This needs to be completed to produce an error
    }
```

Prints

```
Location Services Enabled
Location Services Enabled
```

Yet it still does not update location nor produce an error.

Comment: can you post your view controller declaration?

Comment: Yes, please see the edit.

Comment: you should check before setting the delegate in viewDidLoad `if CLLocationManager.locationServicesEnabled() {` Don't forget to add `locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()` before that

Comment: I have printed this out beforehand and it evaluates to true.  So this is not the problem.  Are you saying that I need to requestAuth before I set the delegate?

Comment: The situation I am running into is that this code works perfectly on the simulator, but not on the device.  What is going wrong here?

Comment: again 1) viewDidLoad 2) `locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()` 3) `if CLLocationManager.locationServicesEnabled() {` 4) `locationManager.delegate = self` 5) `locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest` 6) `locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()`

Comment: I have made the changes you suggested, please see the edit in the question

Comment: Does  print("Location Updated") ever gets called? You should use `locations.last!.coordinate`

Comment: That method is not being called at all when I run the app on a physical device.

Comment: make sure you have in your info.plist the key `NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription` <key>NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription</key>
 <string>Location When In Use message</string>

Answer (score 0):

First you should check if `NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription` is in the appropriate Info.plist, the one for the app. This is because there are many Info.plists in a project, even the GoogleMaps framework has one.

You will notice the app will prompt you to allow obtaining locations once the proper Info.plist has the `NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription`.

Then don't use `locationServicesEnabled` to check if location services is allowed to be used. Use the following instead, this checks the authorization:

```
if CLLocationManager.authorizationStatus == .NotDetermined {
    self.locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
}
self.locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
```

Comment: It does prompt me when I boot the app, and I hit yes.  I do the exact same thing on the device as I did on the simulator.  For some reason it doesn't work on the device like it does on the simluator.

Comment: If you go to Settings->Privacy->Location services, is it on? Does your app also show up on the bottom?

Comment: When the popup shows my the simulator, after I allow it It triggers the didChangeAuthorizationStatus.  No such thing happens after I click allow on my device.

Comment: Yes, yes it does appear in the settings "While Using the App"

Comment: You mentioned that the log doesn't show on the device. It might be the conditional for CLLocationManager.locationServicesEnabled() being false.

Comment: No, I have a print statement inside the block and it does trigger.

Comment: the authorization change function in the delegate does not get called because you set the delegate after you request for authorization

Comment: Is this a problem?  What I am having a hard time unravelling is why it works on the simulator but not a physical device.

Comment: It might be a timing issue for requesting authorization and the delegate methods. This comment section is getting long, stackoverflow suggested to continue in chat.

Comment: How would I get around this timing issue then?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/103361/discussion-between-user3916570-and-bennegeek).